# Load Node 'code' from database while server running

Tags: node.js, express

I'm looking to build my project in a modular fashion so that API endpoints can be added while the server is added.

Adding routes dynamically I should be able to figure out, it's getting the recently uploaded server code running that I can't figure out.

My project has a 'class-per-endpoint' structure. An endpoint has a class attached that can run code and do this and that.

An endpoint can also be dependent on another endpoint/class, **so what I want to be able to do is call the constructor of a dynamically added class and run the code efficiently on the server (without the API calling itself).**

Example where "NewAdder" endpoint was just added. Rudimentary stuff, but I just hope it's clear what I'm trying to achieve. Basically trying to add to the server's code base dynamically.

modifier.ts

```
class Modifier {
    constructor(initiatedBy) {
        this.initBy = initiatedBy;
        this.modifierValue = db.getValue("modifier", {user = this.initBy})
    }
    function modify(toModify) {
        return toModify * this.modifierValue
    }
}
```

newAdder.ts

```
class NewAdder {
    constructor(initiatedBy) {
         this.initBy = initiatedBy;
    }
    modifier = new Modifier(this.initBy);
    function addAndModify(a,b) {
        return modifier.modify(a + b)
    }
}
```

router.ts (this would be dynamic in real life)

```
app.get('/newadder/addandmodify/', function(req, res){
    adder = new NewAdder(req.params.user);
    res.send(adder.addAndModify(req.params.first, req.params.second);
});
```

Hope I made some sense.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research I suppose I could use http to get and then require the module dynamically.

The code will come from our own server, so it should be safe to run in the server.

But if anyone has any idea how to go about this, would be much appreciated.